# Reading Bytes from an InputStreamReader goes into infinite loop

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I've a test which fails because reading bytes from an InputStreamReader is going into infinite loop.

```
@Test
public void testSingleRequest() throws IOException {
        Server server = new Server(9000, 100);
        new Thread(server).start();
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        String payload = "a";
        byte[] load = buildPushPayload(payload);
        out.write(load);
        byte[] response = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        server.stop();

        assertEquals(0, response[0]);


    }
```

This is the code that writes to the InputStream

```
byte[] resp = buildPushResponse();
output.write(resp);

private byte[] buildPushResponse() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        buffer.putInt(0);
        return buffer.array();
    }
```

Both the server and the client are write to the clientSocket Input Output stream.
I can't seem to understand why the infinite loop then?

Comment: I believe "infinite loop' is the wrong term.  I think testSingleRequest is _blocking_ on `IOUtils.toByteArray(in)` - you are asking for the entire stream converted into a byte array. So, toByteArray is waiting until the inputstream is EOF.  You haven't told it how many bytes to read, and the socket is still open.  Instead, you might want to check in.available(), and read that many bytes.  If you are looking for a message based socket, you might want to try websockets.

Comment: @Jamie I'm new to this, can you help me with the code here. Are you suggesting `while(in.available()){ byte[] response = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);}`

Comment: Also should I close the server output stream for the input stream to be not available for the client?

Comment: There is no `InputStreamReader` here. Or any infinite loop either. You don't write bytes to an `InputStream`, and you don't read bytes from a `Reader`: you read characters; and this protocol doesn't contain characters, it contains binary data. It is difficult if not impossible to understand what you're talking about when you use the wrong terms and make false claims. You should be using `DataInputStream`. And yes you should should be closing the output stream at the sender, otherwise you will never receive EOS at the receiver.

Comment: However you can throw all this code away and use `new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeInt(0)` and `int resp = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream().readInt()` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is how to know when to stop reading.  You are calling `IOUtils.toByteArray(in)` which will read until End Of File, which never happens (unless the other side closes their end of the socket).

There are a few schemes you can use to know how many bytes to read from the socket as a message packet before processing the complete message packet.  For example, you could say that all packets are 8 bytes (in which case your read call would specify to read 8 bytes), you could say that the first byte is the count of bytes in the packet, you could say that a packet is variable length, and is terminated with a carriage return byte.

Once you have read a packet, you would normally process the packet and then go back to read another packet or close the socket if you're all done.

Here is a good example of socket programming: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-java/

In that case, they are terminating a packet or message with an End Of Line mark - they are reading one line of text at a time with `DataInputStream.readUTF(socket)`.

```
server = new ServerSocket(port); 
socket = server.accept(); 

// Create a DataInputStream object that takes input from the socket
in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())); 

String message = ""; 

// reads messages from client and prints them
// The loop exits if the message "Over" is received.
try
{ 
    while (!"Over".equals(message))
    { 
        message = in.readUTF(); 
        System.out.println(message); 
    }
}
catch(IOException i) 
{ 
    // handle error
} 
// close connection 
socket.close(); 
in.close();
```

Comment: This code will loop forever at end of stream, because it doesn't handle `EOFException` properly, i.e. by a `break`.

Comment: Modified!  I was foolishly following the example from the site I suggested.

Comment: To do this properly you have to catch `EOFException` separately, as you probably don't want to log it, and then `IOException` which you probably do want to log. Terrible link. Exceptions are caught and printed and then the code proceeds as though they never happened. It fails to check for `null` from `readLine()`. EOS problem as above. Redundant closes. Blocking I/O performed in the constructor. `Socket` as a data member of the same class that has the `ServerSocket`. `System.in` is closed. `ServerSocket` is never closed. Truly terrible code. Don't use these tinpot sites.